# What is the difference between data-driven methods and machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, data

I was wondering (about a more semantic question), is there a difference between *data-driven* methods and *machine learning*? Or is it more correct to state that machine learning is a category of data-driven methods (and what then are other categories)?

Comment: Can you give an example of a data-driven method that is not a machine-learning method?

Comment: You could see a simple t-test as a data-driven method, but I don't perceive this as a machine learning method (although of course they are related).

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6/the-two-cultures-statistics-vs-machine-learning

Comment: Thanks for the interesting discusion, though perhaps not conclusive for this question?

Comment: "data-driven method" doesn't seem to be a well-defined term. so this question seems rather opinion based... maybe you can give a reference to where you came across this term repeatedly

Comment: I quote from this [paper](https://ti.arc.nasa.gov/m/pub-archive/1442h/1442%20(Goebel).pdf): "Common to data-driven approaches is the modeling of desired system output (but not necessarily of the mechanics of the system) using historical data. Such approaches encompass “conventional” numerical algorithms, like linear regression or Kalman filters, as well algorithms that are commonly found in the machine learning and data mining communities." However, I think it is safe to state that machine learning methods are data-driven, just as for example other data-mining methods.

Comment: To me, machne learning is all about driving data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the quotation you have added in your comments, data-driven approaches are approaches where you use data that describes past states ("historical data") to get a (not defined) system to give a desired output.

To understand whether this definition includes machine learning or not we will have to define "machine learning", and while there could be plenty of ways to define it I expect that it will be quite difficult to come up with a definition that does not include within it "Using a system that, based on given states will give a desired output".

Note that in this last definition I use "given states" and not "past states" as to include approaches such as online learning.

Bottom line is that unless you really want to hold to a narrow definition of "past states" it seems that machine learning approaches **are** a subset of data-driven approaches.

Answer (score 1):

In my view, Empirical Likelihood method is a very data-driven method but it has nothing to do with machine learning. Here is a link talking about the Empirical Likelihood method:

[Empirical Likelihood Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_likelihood)